# MS Chart Control Scale - Line graph show 12 months

Tags: c#, asp.net, mschart, linegraph

On my X Axis, I have months. The chart shows up to 11 points, i.e. Jan - Nov of the same year, but when I add 12 points (Jan - Dec), it will do an auto label thing and change the interval for every 4 months.

How can I change the graph so that it shows 12 months before it does the auto labels?

Here is the server control code I am currently using.

```
<asp:CHART ID="Chart1" runat="server" 
    BorderColor="181, 64, 1" BorderDashStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="2" Height="296px" 
    ImageLocation="~/TempImages/ChartPic_#SEQ(300,3)" ImageType="Png" 
    Palette="None" Width="700px" 
    BorderlineColor="">
        <legends>
            <asp:Legend BackColor="Transparent" 
                                    Font="Trebuchet MS, 8pt, style=Bold" 
                IsTextAutoFit="False" Name="Default" Alignment="Center" 
                DockedToChartArea="ChartArea1" Docking="Top" IsDockedInsideChartArea="False" 
                Title="Legend">
            </asp:Legend>
        </legends>
        <series>
            <asp:Series BorderColor="180, 26, 59, 105" BorderWidth="2" ChartType="Line" 
                                    Color="220, 65, 140, 240" MarkerSize="6" 
                Name="Series1" ShadowColor="Black" 
                                    ShadowOffset="2" XValueType="DateTime" YValueType="Double" 
                                    LabelFormat="c0" LegendText="Actual" 
                MarkerStyle="Circle">
            </asp:Series>
            <asp:Series BorderColor="180, 26, 59, 105" BorderWidth="2" ChartType="Line" 
                                    Color="220, 224, 64, 10" MarkerSize="6" Name="Series2" ShadowColor="Black" 
                                    ShadowOffset="2" XValueType="DateTime" YValueType="Double" 
                                    LabelFormat="c0" LegendText="Projected" 
                MarkerStyle="Circle">
            </asp:Series>
            <asp:Series BorderColor="180, 26, 59, 105" BorderWidth="2" 
                ChartArea="ChartArea1" ChartType="Line" 
                                    Legend="Default" Name="Series3" LabelFormat="c0" XValueType="DateTime" 
                                    YValueType="Double" Color="0, 192, 192" MarkerSize="6" 
                ShadowColor="Black" ShadowOffset="2" LegendText="Actual Credit Limit" 
                MarkerStyle="Circle">
            </asp:Series>
        </series>
        <chartareas>
            <asp:ChartArea BackColor="#DEEDF7" BackGradientStyle="TopBottom" 
                                    BackSecondaryColor="White" BorderColor="64, 64, 64, 64" BorderDashStyle="Solid" 
                                    Name="ChartArea1" ShadowColor="Transparent">
                <area3dstyle inclination="40" isclustered="False" isrightangleaxes="False" 
                                        lightstyle="Realistic" perspective="9" rotation="25" wallwidth="3" />
                <axisy linecolor="64, 64, 64, 64" islabelautofit="False" 
                                        isstartedfromzero="False">
                    <LabelStyle Font="Trebuchet MS, 8.25pt, style=Bold" Format="c0" />
                    <majorgrid linecolor="64, 64, 64, 64" />
                </axisy>
                <axisx linecolor="64, 64, 64, 64" intervaloffsettype="Months" 
                                        intervaltype="Months" islabelautofit="False" isstartedfromzero="False">
                    <LabelStyle Font="Trebuchet MS, 8.25pt, style=Bold" Angle="-60" 
                                            Format="MMM yy" />
                    <majorgrid linecolor="64, 64, 64, 64" />
                </axisx>
            </asp:ChartArea>
        </chartareas>
    </asp:CHART>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to change the Chart's Width to a higher value...

```
<asp:Chart ID="Chart1" runat="server" 
BorderColor="181, 64, 1" BorderDashStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="2" Height="296px" 
ImageLocation="~/TempImages/ChartPic_#SEQ(300,3)" ImageType="Png" 
Palette="None" Width="800px" 
BorderlineColor="">
```

Try to set the inverval property to 1 on axisx:

```
 <axisx Interval="1" linecolor="64, 64, 64, 64" intervaloffsettype="Months" 
  intervaltype="Months" islabelautofit="False" isstartedfromzero="False">
```

To fully understand how to format chart axis, take a look at:

[Formatting Axis Labels on a Chart](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/bb934421(v=sql.105))

[image]
<sub>(source: [microsoft.com](http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/dynimg/IC138697.gif))</sub>

**How the Chart Calculates Axis Label Intervals?**

On the **category axis**, the minimum and maximum value types are determined depending on the type of your category field. Any field in a dataset can be categorized into one of three category field types: Numeric, Date/Time and Strings.

**Displaying All Labels on the Category Axis**

On the value axis, axis intervals provide a consistent measure of the data points on the chart. However, on the **category axis**, this functionality can cause categories to appear without axis labels. Typically, you want all categories to be labeled. You can set the number of intervals to 1 to show all categories. For more information, see [How to: Specify an Axis Interval](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/cc281177(v=sql.105)).

Comment: @Mike: try different values for Width... higher ones like 1000px, 1250px, etc... see if this changes something.

Comment: I've tried different heights and widths of the graphs, and it didn't change anything. I even tried 2000px, and height 600px. It still does the same thing.

Comment: Okay, so changing the Interval to 1, allows as many months on the x axis of the chart, so I can see my 12 months, except, if the user queries data that has 128 months, the months are squashed.

I guess I could check how many points are being queried, and change the interval if there is 12 or less, otherwise, leave the interval at auto

Comment: @Mike: That's it. From MSDN we have: Note
When an axis interval is set, all automatic labeling is disabled. If you specify a value for the axis interval, you might experience unpredictable labeling behavior, depending on how many categories are on the category axis.

Comment: Thank you so much for your direction, Leniel. This probably would have driven me insane!

Comment: @Mike. You're welcome Mike. I'm here to help. It's always a pleasure to help.

Answer (score 0):

Use Microsoft chart

```
chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.ScaleBreakStyle = true
```

to chart the second set of values in thier on Y Axis with thier own Y values